# javascript to create a button with onclick

Tags: javascript, dom, createelement

I'm trying to use javascript to create a button that has a onclick event that calls a function  defined in the head that takes in as parameter a dom object relative to the button. how do i do this?

ex:

```
<html>
<head> <script>function blah(obj){alert(obj.value)}</script></head>
<body>
<button onclick="blah(this.parentNode.value);"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
var newButton = document.createElement("button");
???
```

in the end i want the new button to be the same as the existing one.

Comment: could you explain why you're doing this, perhaps a better solution exists for what you're doing..

Comment: its kinda (unnecesarily) complicated but i'll try. so the original button will create a bunch of stuff and delete itself. Among the created stuff is another button that will recreate the original button which could create another bunch of stuff and so on

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
function createButton(context, func) {
    var button = document.createElement("input");
    button.type = "button";
    button.value = "im a button";
    button.onclick = func;
    context.appendChild(button);
}

window.onload = function() {
    createButton(document.body, function() {
        highlight(this.parentNode.childNodes[1]);
        // Example of different context, copied function etc
        // createButton(this.parentNode, this.onclick);
    });
};
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: i dont think it solves the DOM problem where the argument passed in is relative to the button :(

Comment: @zaftcoAgeiha I have no idea what that means. Could you explain what you want please. Edit :: Check the post again.

Comment: ok i need to be able to dynamically create this
<button onClick="highlight(this.parentNode.childNodes[1])">highlight</button> and have it clickable

Comment: i get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined". i think the problem is that javascript thinks that "this" refers to the js object as opposed to the html dom obj

Comment: @zaftcoAgeiha It's possibly because I typed out 'childNotes' instead of 'childNodes'... The code works.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the built-in setAttrbute javascript function.

```js
var newButton = document.createElement("button")
newButton.setAttribute("onclick", "blah(this.parentNode.value)")
```

Hope it will help