# Javascript for submitting form button

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I want to produce buttons through Javascript that can also do the form function. Here is how i am doing but my form function does not work when i click. Please help me out on this.

External Javascript

```
var onef    
onef="Apple"    
var twof    
twof="Orange"
```

Now this is what i am doing in HTML page

```
<script>
    document.write("<button>")      
    document.write(onef)    
    onClick=("this.form.T4.value++;")
</script>
<script>
    document.write("<button>")
    document.write(twof)
    onClick=("this.form.T5.value++;")
</script>
```

The script works right but onClick function not working.

Comment: what do you want the onClick happens on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript to create a button with onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650975/javascript-to-create-a-button-with-onclick)

Answer (score 0):

ouldn't you have to do this:

```
<script>
    document.write("<button ")      
    document.write('onClick="this.form.T4.value++;">')
    document.write(onef)    
    document.write("</button>")
</script>
```

What you are doing in your original code is building the string "<button>apple" and creating a variable called onClick with a value of "this.form.T4.value++;". What I believe you need to do is build a string with the whole button tag in it, which is what the code above is doing.

Comment: can u also help me on this as well:
I am trying to minus the value of "f1" from "f2" but when i click the button it reuces everytime the value of f1

        <form name=bills>
 <p><input type="text" name="f1" size="20">
 <input type="text" name="f2" size="20" value="30"></p>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="cbs(this.form)" name="B1">
        <Script>
        function cbs(form)
        {
            form.f2.value = (([document.bills.f2.value] * 1) - (document.bills.f1.value * 1))
        }
</Script>
        

pls help

Comment: Try removing the square backets from around document.bills.f2.value. Also, if your original question was answers, would you mind marking this a the answer? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see an end form tag in what you pasted? I believe that may be the issue.

Comment: Since this answer seemed to solve your issue, would you minde accepting it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen code like this before for creating a button with JavaScript. I would go with something more like this;

```
var onef ="Apple";
var twof ="Orange"; 

function createButton(context, func, text){
    var button = document.createElement("input");
    button.type = "button";
    button.value = text;
    button.onclick = func;
    context.appendChild(button);
}

createButton(document.body, function(){ this.form.T4.value++; }, onef);
createButton(document.body, function(){ this.form.T5.value++; }, twof);
```

An example can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/4yV4V/

This gives you some reusable code for creating the button and passing in what ever you want the `onclick` even to be. Also you could customise this code for other situations.